# Is there any way to get google cloud task status?

Tags: python, google-cloud-tasks

I am using python and google.cloud.tasks_v2. After deploying my service in app engine I create task and it creates and executing successfully, but how I can get the task status or the result of task execution if method client.get_task() do not return any information about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting information about a specified Cloud Task that you are running, you can use  the [command line](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/tasks/describe) and integrate it into your Python's code using a package like `subprocess` to run the following command:

`gcloud tasks describe TASK [--queue=QUEUE]`

Moreover, if you would like to see the status of a task attempt you can use the following for the [Cloud Task API.](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#attempt)

It will give you information about the status of a task attempt with the following JSON representation:

```
{
  "scheduleTime": string,
  "dispatchTime": string,
  "responseTime": string,
  "responseStatus": {
    object (Status)
  }
}
```

To see the status of the task's first attempt `firstAttempt` or the status of the task's last attempt `lastAttempt` you can use the [following method](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks) within the Cloud Task API.

As stated [here,](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#appenginehttprequest) please bear in mind that if you are using App Engine tasks within a Cloud Tasks queue, the code status will be as follow:

> The task attempt has succeeded if the app's request handler returns an HTTP response code in the range [200 - 299]. The task attempt has failed if the app's handler returns a non-2xx response code or Cloud Tasks does not receive response before the deadline.