# How can I see executed Google Cloud task and whether they failed or succeeded

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

How can I see executed Google Cloud task and whether they failed or succeeded?

Currently I only see this even though my task has been executed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cloud Task API](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest) to see the status of a task attempt. This will show the status of the task attempt with the following JSON representation:

```
{
  "scheduleTime": string,
  "dispatchTime": string,
  "responseTime": string,
  "responseStatus": {
    object (Status)
  }
}
```

This [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59469449/18265638) covers how to get Google Cloud Task status.Here is the [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123687557) to get metrics for an individual Cloud Task as there is no metric available for monitoring an individual task.

Comment: That is not practical but ok thx i guess google doesnt care about google cloud

Comment: maybe you can add your concern over the feature request or create a new [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/) by referencing this

Comment: If google will pay me for improving their products i would be happy to first they don't take feature request serious enough second i don't have time i have actual work to do. We will rewrite this in .net soon so there is no need. Thank you for the fast reply

Comment: @Dživo Jelić I think you should give a try by raising issue tracker instead of leaving.

Comment: Hi @Dživo Jelić Have you raised the issue tracker?If yes, can you please share it here, so that if anyone is facing the same issue will also add their concern